# php - postgresql max execution time

Tags: php, postgresql

Is there an option to use with PostgreSQL Functions in PHP, so you can specify a maxim execution time for a query ? I don't want to enable this from the config file because only certain queries need to be restricted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

run from php a query before the main query

[like](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-set.html)

```
SET statement_timeout TO 5000;
```

Comment: Note that you can also set this by user or database:

alter user bogouser set statement_timeout = '60s';

Comment: @Halim Evgi is there any chance to make this query as global setting like setting the timeout for postgresql query in php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_time_limit()` According to PHP doc:

`When called, set_time_limit() restarts the timeout counter from zero. In other words, if the timeout is the default 30 seconds, and 25 seconds into script execution a call such as set_time_limit(20) is made, the script will run for a total of 45 seconds before timing out`.